# Magento: display multi-selection as a list with unique ID' s so list item can be changed to an image using CSS

Tags: magento

I figured out how to display my custom multiselection attributie as a list but havent been able to figure out how to add an ID or class to every list item. This would allow me to display an image using CSS instead of text.

Hope you guys can help me. By the way, this is the code I use to display my custom attribute "rating" as a list:

```
        <?php if($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)): ?>
        <ul><li><?php
        $_comma = ",";
        $_list = "</li><li>";
        echo str_replace($_comma,$_list,$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product))    ?>    
        </li></ul>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact format of the return of your function, I can't be 100% sure, but I think this would do the trick:

```
    <div>
    <?php if($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)):?>
        <ul>
        <?php $i=0?>
        <?php foreach(explode(',', $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) as $value) : ?>
            <li id="value_<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $value ?></li>
            <?php $i++ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>
```

It would probably be a little easier to just modify your return to give you back an array, but if the return is a comma separated list and not easy to change, then explode should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looking at your code snippet it looks decent but it is not working for me. In fact, every data beyond this code snippet is gone. So it kinda destroys my site. Any other suggestions? How would I set it to return me an array?

Comment: Then it means something is erroring out in the code. You could try plugging debug statements between php calls and see where it stops executing. Code snippet was just an example of form, as I don't have access to your site for testing, I can't be sure what will work and what will not, in short, wasn't intended to be cut & paste ready.

It was also missing a paren and an opening div tag, try now.